# Recovering encrypted home directory after UID change

Tags: mount, encryption, ecryptfs, btrfs

When I log into my Ubuntu system I see only two files in my `$HOME` directory:

- Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop
- README.txt

I believe this happened because I changed the UID of my user.  I can see the files mounted in the `/tmp` directory if I do:

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private
```

Do I just copy/move these files back to my home directory?  Why is this directory not mounted if I can recover it so trivially?

I am running an encrypted BTRFS `/home` partition.  It also looks like my own user is separately encrypted but I don't have good notes on this.

Comment: Yes, it's due to encryption and because you changed your user. That's what drive/folder encryption was invented for. Ans yes, if you can decrypt it, you do what you want with the contents.

Comment: If I move the files back to my $HOME directory are they re-encrypted?  Also, what do I do with the two files.  Just delete them?

Comment: They will if the the target location is encrypted, they won't otherwise (i don't understand the confusion here). Once copied, again, you do what you want with the "old files".

Comment: I guess I don't understand how my private directory was encrypted in the first place.  The `/home` directory is encrypted but it's able to mount it.  But it looks like my `$HOME` directory was encrypted separately in a way I don't remember.  I want to reproduce this but I don't know how.

Comment: Encryption, full or $HOME only, are options you can choose in the installation process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the UID on the encrypted folders.  `usermod` didn't do that for me automatically.  Specifically, I did:

```
sudo chown -R newUID /home/.ecryptfs/myUser
```

Then I rebooted.